# PSQLException when connecting to Postgres server via JDBC in same LAN (PGAdmin works)

Tags: database, postgresql, jdbc, dbvisualizer

I have some severe problems with connecting from DBVisualizer (8.0.9) to a PostgreSQL server which is running in the same LAN. DBVis is Java-based thus uses JDBC for connection. Connecting from PGAdmin works like a charm - only DBVis connection via JDBC isn't. And I need that to be solved!

```
Specs:
My PC: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64Bit), IP: 192.168.110.193
Server OS: Suse LINUX Enterprise Server 11, IP: 192.168.110.12
Postgresql server version: 9.1
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
Java Version: 1.6.0_33
Java Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
OS Name: Linux
OS Arch: amd64
OS Version: 3.2.0-25-generic
```

When starting a connection, I'm getting a "Connecting..." message and after ~5 minutes of waiting the following error message appears in the **connection window**:

```
"An error occurred while establishing the connection:
Long Message:
The connection attempt failed.
Details:
Type: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException
SQL State: 08001"
```

In the **debug console** I get:

```
12:04:57 [DEBUG pool-2-thread-8 D.ā] RootConnection: Driver.acceptsURL("jdbc:postgresql://192.168.110.12:5432/MYDATABASE")
12:04:57 [DEBUG pool-2-thread-8 D.ā] RootConnection: Driver.connect("jdbc:postgresql://192.168.110.12:5432/MYDATABASE", {user=******, password=******})
12:24:58 [DEBUG pool-2-thread-8 D.ā] RootConnection: EXCEPTION -> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
```

The debugging information of the **JDBC driver** is also provided:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:150)
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:30)
at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at com.onseven.dbvis.d.B.D.ā(Z:1548)
at com.onseven.dbvis.d.B.F$A.call(Z:278)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

For convenience the relevant part of the server's **pg_hba.conf**:

```
#"local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local all all peer

#IPv4 local connections:
host all all 192.168.110.0/24 md5

#IPv6 local connections:
host all all ::1/128 md5
```

And the relevant parts of the **postgresql.conf**:

```
# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'                  # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost', '*' = all
                                        # (change requires restart)
#port = 5432                            # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
# Note:  Increasing max_connections costs ~400 bytes of shared memory per
# connection slot, plus lock space (see max_locks_per_transaction).
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3     # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_directory = ''             # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''                 # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777         # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                                        # (change requires restart)
#bonjour = off                          # advertise server via Bonjour
                                        # (change requires restart)
#bonjour_name = ''                      # defaults to the computer name
                                        # (change requires restart)

# - Security and Authentication -

#authentication_timeout = 1min          # 1s-600s
#ssl = off                              # (change requires restart)
#ssl_ciphers = 'ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH'      # allowed SSL ciphers
                                        # (change requires restart)
#ssl_renegotiation_limit = 512MB        # amount of data between renegotiations
#password_encryption = on
#db_user_namespace = off

# Kerberos and GSSAPI
#krb_server_keyfile = ''
#krb_srvname = 'postgres'               # (Kerberos only)
#krb_caseins_users = off

# - TCP Keepalives -
# see "man 7 tcp" for details

#tcp_keepalives_idle = 0                # TCP_KEEPIDLE, in seconds;
                                        # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_keepalives_interval = 0            # TCP_KEEPINTVL, in seconds;
                                        # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_keepalives_count = 0               # TCP_KEEPCNT;
                                        # 0 selects the system default
```

Comment: What is the IP address of your client?

Comment: I already mentioned it in my start post under 'specs'. For convenience: 192.168.110.193

Comment: Ah, sorry I only saw the server IP there. Any firewalls/proxies involved?

Comment: Yes, we have a proxy for connecting to the internet. Might this interfere with the JDBC driver? I thought that - as long the connection is established within the LAN - the presence of a proxy should not affect that?! I temporarily shut down the firewall on that local server but that didn't fix it.

Comment: I think (!! not sure) that the presence of a proxy means the PostgreSQL server will see the proxy's IP address and not your client address. Is the proxy's IP address in the same IP range as configured by pg_hba.conf?

Comment: Just to make sure that the proxy is not interfering connections in the local subnet, I added the proxy IP to the pg_hba.conf, but after restart it didn't change anything -> reason must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection is running now but unfortunately I cannot exactly tell the steps that led to the solution. Anyway, I will try to sketch them:

I installed an old version of DBVisualizer (7.1.5) and was able to successfully establish a connection to the db server. Then I went straight back to the 8.0.9
version of DBVis and tested the connection again. Unexpectedly, the connection also worked here, even though I didn't change configurations - neither in my DBVis 8.0.9 installation nor on the DB server. That's it. Maybe someone has some some more clues on that issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error code 08001 is a generic error code telling that the JDBC driver could not connect to the database. The reason for this could be many.

You should enter the IP address or DNS name of the server where the database runs as the Database Server and the Database Port it listens to for TCP/IP connections, by default 5432.

After you have entered this, please use the Ping Server button to see if you can reach that server and port. If you get an error message, you have either entered incorrect Database Server or Port values, there is a firewall that blocks the connection, or the PostgreSQL server is not configured to access connections from your PC. If Ping Server says everything is fine but you still cannot connect, the problem is most likely with the login credentials for the user account you specify.